# Measuring latency TCP/UDP between 2 boards

Tags: python, raspberrypi

I am sending and recieving packets between two boards (a Jeston and a Pi). I tried using TCP then UDP, theoritically UDP is faster but I want to verify this with numbers. I want to be able to run my scripts, send and recieve my packets while also calculating the latency. I will later study the effect of using RF modules instead of direct cables between the two boards on the latency (this is another reason why I want the numbers).

What is the right way to tackle this?

I tried sending the timestamps to get the difference but their times are not synched. I read about NTP and Iperf but I am not sure how they can be run within my scripts. iperf measures the trafic but how can that be accurate if your real TCP or UDP application is not running with real packets being exchanged?

Comment: Hello. This sounds interesting BUT what does it have to do with the Ubuntu OS?

Comment: iperf, iperf3, hping3 and others are great tools for determining network and hardware limits, not your application limits.

Comment: @Doug smythies thank you for pointing this out, the same idea was going through my mind. what is the right way to measure my application limits?

Comment: @David I know, I was looking for answers everywhere, My boards are running Ubuntu, and I was reading about enabling NTP on them, I was hoping to get guidance on that if that was the correcr way to measure latency.

Comment: I don't know your application, but maybe you could add code to accumulate and calculate statistics directly within.

Comment: @DougSmythies can you elaborate? statistics of what exactly?

Comment: I have no idea, it's your application.

Answer (score 1):

Sync the clocks with something like PTP, use iperf 2 and the [--trip-times option](https://iperf2.sourceforge.io/iperf-manpage.html)